# Mouse right-click inoperative in Pharo 2.0 and 3.0 under Windows XP and 7

Tags: pharo

I installed Pharo 3.0 on my ASUS Windows 7 laptop and settled in to run through the ProfStef tutorial. But I could not get past the first panel - I could not 'doit'.

I installed Pharo 2.0 on the laptop. Same story. I turned on the touchpad. Nope. I installed Pharo 2.0 and 3.0 on a Windows 7 desktop. No, the mouse right button is not recognized there.

I installed Pharo 2.0 on a Gateway Windows XP and the right-mouse button did not work there either.

Finally, knowing that Pharo is a fork of Squeak, I installed Squeak 4.3 on the original laptop. The right-click is recognized by that package.

Does right-click means something in Pharo other than what I am expecting?

Comment: I just discovered that I greatly overstated this problem. The right-click _is_ recognized in the tutorial workspace windows. The 'Browse Tutorials' window is the place where the right-click does not trigger a context menu. (I'm not ruling out the possibility of other instances - I have not experimented a lot.)

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a known issue.
Reference [here](http://code.google.com/p/pharo/issues/detail?id=7586&q=mouse&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Milestone%20Difficulty) on the Pharo Open Issues area.
I didn't create a user to dig deeper at the link provided there, but you can check it out.
My guess is that, since it's pretty darn important, it will be resolved soon.

Answer (score 0):

This is very likely a VM problem. The latest update on this issue is from February 14 2013, work still in progress.

Pharo and Squeak use different VMs, which explains the different behaviours you're seeing.

To evaluate an expression (i.e. "doit") you don't need the right click. You can simply use `ctrl + d` (or `alt + d`, I'm on Mac, so I don't know which one's the command button). So simply select the code you want to evaluate and "doit" and you're good.
If you want feedback, you can also "print it" (`ctrl + p`), "inspect it" (`ctrl + i`) or "explore it" (`ctrl + shift + i`).

Answer (score 0):

I have raised the priority of that issue (case 7545 on FogBugz) so we have a look at it before releasing Pharo3

Comment: The defect is still present in the 30845 update on Windows 7. Selected Pharo Tutorials from the World menu. Expanded Pharo Syntax Tutorial. Clicked Welcome. Highlighted 'PharoTutorial next.' Right-click of mouse does nothing. Alternately, Alt-D does perform the do-it action. Once the new tutorial window opens, then right-click works as advertised. It is just that first panel where it is non-functional. Unfortunately, that panel tells the user "right-click and choose 'do it (d)'"

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not. That's not related: it has something to do with the following of implementors when pressing over a class or a selector. And btw, that issue tracker is not active anymore (that issue is old, more than a year). We should close it, but we let it there for documentation issues. For now, we are using https://pharo.fogbugz.com.

Anyway... about your problem: I couldn't reproduce it. How are you installing your pharo distributions?
I tried two ways:

http://get.pharo.org

(it works in windows if you have a decent shell installed)

and the pharo launcher:

https://ci.inria.fr/pharo-contribution/job/PharoLauncher-Win-Package/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/pharo-ci/pharo_installer.exe

Both are "the recommended" ways of installing, even if they are not properly publicised in the pharo web site (something that we should change during the course of the day :) )

Comment: I used the zip files shown on the pharo-download page. Then I used Windows to extract all files into the relative directory.